# Lenovo Laptop P14s Gen 4 drivers problem

Tags: drivers, lenovo, laptop

I'm attempting to set up a new Lenovo P14s with Ubuntu 20.04 because that's the version we use for our software stack. At first, 20.04 wouldn't install properly - it gave some error that I couldn't resolve (even though posts I read said that the error could simply be ignored, the system wouldn't boot). So I thought I'd force the issue, installed 18.04 then upgraded to 20.04. This works, I can now boot into the system, but I'm missing drivers for the trackpad and the wifi card. On Windows, this is super simple and can be done through the Lenovo System Update - but I don't know of such a thing for Ubuntu.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Where might I find the right drivers?

```
xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3  [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=9  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13 [slave  keyboard (3)]

lspci -nnk -d ::0280 00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)       Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0090]

sudo hwinfo | grep -i synap > no output
sudo lshw | grep -i synap > no output
```

Tried to install kernel 6.5:

I installed 6.5, but then got an issue when the machine boots, saying:

pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid.

I actually had this problem originally when I was trying to install 20.04 on this P14s Gen 4 (and another, exactly the same laptop, just to confirm), so I'm not sure this is going to be possible :/

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Why do you say you are missing drivers? Are the devices not detected? Are they detected but they don't work? Both the wifi and trackpad of the P14s should be fine with the normal `iwlwifi` and synaptic drivers. I don't see the trackpad in your `xinput` output, only the trackpoint. Do you have any output for `sudo hwinfo | grep -i synap` or `sudo lshw | grep -i synap`?

Comment: Hi terdon, thank you so much for your comment. I say missing drivers because they don't work - forgive my ignorance, but I would assume that means missing drivers. I'm not very familiar with Linux in general. The WiFi isn't detected - when I do ifconfig, I don't see a WiFi adapter there. I ran both of the commands you suggested and didn't get any output :/

Comment: That is really strange. I am writing this from my own P14s, running Arch instead of Ubuntu, but still, and it works fine. If neither of the two commands I gave detect it, then it means the hardware isn't detected at all. Could you have turned off the wifi using the keyboard shortcut (Fn+F8 on mine). Does re-enabling it that way make it appear in `ifconfig`? My P14s doesn't have a button to disable the trackpad, but let's startwith the wifi.

Comment: Attach output of `lspci -nnk -d ::0280` command

Comment: Thank you both for further comments. I checked the Fn+F8 - that enables Airplane mode, so unfortunately it wasn't that simple! It could be that this is a P14s Gen 4 (fairly new generation). All the P14s Gen 3s that I have built with Ubuntu 20.04 have worked fine, so I think it could be a slight change of hardware in this new generation...
lspci -nnk -d ::0280 
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
      Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0090]

Comment: Please attach output to the main post body (edit the post)

Comment: You got to have Linux 5.18+ for your Wi-Fi to work https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-51f1-1a56-1671

Comment: Is there a way to update the kernel to 5.18+ whilst staying on 20.04?

Comment: Install 6.5 using this tutorial:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/08/install-latest-kernel-new-repository/

Comment: Thanks again. I installed 6.5, but then got an issue when the machine boots, saying pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid. Everything I search for regarding this says that you can ignore it, however the machine doesn't boot. So I'm a bit stuck :/