# lshw -C shows Network Controller UNCLAIMED and incorrect product name (Ubuntu 20 fresh install, Dell Precision 3581)

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

Doing an install of Ubuntu 20 on a brand new Dell Precision 3581. The high level problem is that wired connections work but there's no wireless options in the Network settings (i.e. the wireless network adapter isn't being found).

I tried manually installing the Intel network drivers (https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-error). I've also played around with BIOS settings (using Dell BIOS 1.4.1, I've turned Fast Boot options off, enabled UEFI Network Stack). But haven't really gotten any progress.

The strange thing is that in any of the other posts I've been able to find about this problem, they all at least have an actual product name for the network device when they run `lshw` and so those posts have answers relavant to their hardware, but all mine says is "Intel Corporation". Not sure what that means though.

Also, I'd prefer to be using the 20.04 HWE kernel but have tried both.

```
$ sudo nmcli device
DEVICE     TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s31f6  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo         loopback  unmanaged  --  

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:62631a4000-62631a7fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 01
       serial: 4c:d7:17:11:81:ff
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-88-generic duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=10.69.152.135 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:131 memory:9f280000-9f29ffff
```

Additional troubleshooting commands:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0c07]

---------

$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
$ 

---------

$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for the Welcome! Long time lurker first time asker :)

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`: 

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0c07]


`sudo modprobe iwlwifi`: empty response

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl``: empty response

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488786/lenovo-laptop-p14s-gen-4-drivers-problem I suggest you try a live session of 22.04 LTS or even 23.10. Install which ever one works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: `8086:4090` from your `lspci` output points at an Intel AX211 card.  Support for this was *NOT* mainstream until 22.04+.  You've found a solution by using a different kernel which packages a different set of iwlwifi, etc. but upgrading to 22.04 or using the 20.04 HWE kernel will be your solution.

Answer (score 2):

There were three alternate kernel versions that were able to work with my wifi chip and fixed overall the wifi issue:

- [6.5.1-zabbly+](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/08/install-latest-kernel-new-repository/)
- 5.15.0.67-generic
- 5.15.0-46-generic

I ended up using .67 for my own applications, but all three worked

Comment: This is because 20.04 is too old to support the AX211 card.  Support for that series was not made available until the kernels you indicated or Ubuntu 22.04.  My suggestion would be upgrade to 22.04 for continued hardware support, or install the HWE kernel for 22.04